# PHP Mail Form - Only one variable is submitting

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, email

I'm trying to set up a PHP mail form. I started with [this guide](https://www.sanwebe.com/2014/04/ajax-contact-form-attachment-jquery-php/comment-page-1#comments) and have been modifying things slightly as I go. Currently, I'm getting the form to submit, I'm receiving the email, but only the comments written in the text area are populating the body of the email.

My PHP Code:

```html
<?php
$recipient_email    = "my@email.com"; //recepient
$from_email         = "from@email.com"; //from email using site domain.


if(!isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) AND strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) != 'xmlhttprequest') {
 die('Sorry, request must be Ajax POST'); //exit script
}

if($_POST){
    
    $sender_name  = filter_var($_POST["name"], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING); //capture sender name
    $sender_email  = filter_var($_POST["email"], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING); //capture sender email
    $phone_number   = filter_var($_POST["telephone"], FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);
    $subject        = "Contact Form Entry";
    $message   = filter_var($_POST["comments"], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING); //capture message

    $attachments = $_FILES['file_attach'];
 
    //php validation
    if(strlen($sender_name)<4){ // If length is less than 4 it will output JSON error.
        print json_encode(array('type'=>'error', 'text' => 'Name is too short or empty!'));
        exit;
    }
    if(!filter_var($sender_email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)){ //email validation
        print json_encode(array('type'=>'error', 'text' => 'Please enter a valid email!'));
        exit;
    }
    if(!filter_var($phone_number, FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_FLOAT)){ //check for valid numbers in phone number field
        print json_encode(array('type'=>'error', 'text' => 'Enter only digits in phone number'));
        exit;
    }
    if(strlen($message)<3){ //check emtpy message
        print json_encode(array('type'=>'error', 'text' => 'Too short message! Please enter something.'));
        exit;
    }

    
    $file_count = count($attachments['name']); //count total files attached
    $boundary = md5("whatever"); 
            
    if($file_count > 0){ //if attachment exists
        //header
        $headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n"; 
        $headers .= "From:".$from_email."\r\n"; 
        $headers .= "Reply-To: ".$sender_email."" . "\r\n";
        $headers .= "Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary = $boundary\r\n\r\n"; 
        
        //message text
        $body = "--$boundary\r\n";
        $body .= "Content-Type: text/plain; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";
        $body .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\r\n\r\n"; 
        $body .= chunk_split(base64_encode($message)); 

        //attachments
        for ($x = 0; $x < $file_count; $x++){       
            if(!empty($attachments['name'][$x])){
                
                if($attachments['error'][$x]>0) //exit script and output error if we encounter any
                {
                    $mymsg = array( 
                    1=>"The uploaded file exceeds the upload_max_filesize directive in php.ini", 
                    2=>"The uploaded file exceeds the MAX_FILE_SIZE directive that was specified in the HTML form", 
                    3=>"The uploaded file was only partially uploaded", 
                    4=>"No file was uploaded", 
                    6=>"Missing a temporary folder" ); 
                    print  json_encode( array('type'=>'error',$mymsg[$attachments['error'][$x]]) ); 
     exit;
                }
                
                //get file info
                $file_name = $attachments['name'][$x];
                $file_size = $attachments['size'][$x];
                $file_type = $attachments['type'][$x];
                
                //read file 
                $handle = fopen($attachments['tmp_name'][$x], "r");
                $content = fread($handle, $file_size);
                fclose($handle);
                $encoded_content = chunk_split(base64_encode($content)); //split into smaller chunks (RFC 2045)
                
                $body .= "--$boundary\r\n";
                $body .="Content-Type: $file_type; name=".$file_name."\r\n";
                $body .="Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=".$file_name."\r\n";
                $body .="Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\r\n";
                $body .="X-Attachment-Id: ".rand(1000,99999)."\r\n\r\n"; 
                $body .= $encoded_content; 
            }
        }

    }else{ //send plain email otherwise
       $headers = "From:".$from_email."\r\n".
        "Reply-To: ".$sender_email. "\n" .
        "X-Mailer: PHP/" . phpversion();

        $body = "Name: " . $sender_name . "\r\n";
        $body .= "Email: " . $sender_email . "\r\n";
        $body .= "Comments: " . $message . "\r\n";
        $body .= "Telephone: ".$phone_number . "\r\n";
    }
        
    $sentMail = mail($recipient_email, $subject, $body, $headers);
    if($sentMail) //output success or failure messages
    {       
        print json_encode(array('type'=>'done', 'text' => 'Thank you for your email'));
  exit;
    }else{
        print json_encode(array('type'=>'error', 'text' => 'Could not send mail! Please check your PHP mail configuration.'));  
  exit;
    }
}
?>
```

I've been testing it mostly without an image attachment, so the code should jump to the *}else{ //send plain email otherwise* section.

```
$body = "Name: " . $sender_name . "\r\n";
$body .= "Email: " . $sender_email . "\r\n";
$body .= "Comments: " . $message . "\r\n";
$body .= "Telephone: ".$phone_number . "\r\n";
```

With this code included, I'm wondering why all of these lines aren't concatenating into the body variable, and sending all of this info when the `mail()` function is fired. The email I receive only consists of what was written in the `textarea` on the form. Any insight?

Comment: 'the code _should_ jump'... Are you sure `$file_count` equals to `0`? Please run a `var_dump($file_count);`

Comment: Your headers should be separated by `\r\n`, my guess is that it's munging the other lines into the email header.

Comment: @PetervanderWal Totally naive to how PHP works, so not knowing how to run a var_dump, your comment inspired me to remove the if/else statement entirely and just leave the code that was in the else block. This actually ended up sending everything that it should send! So I guess this confirms that the problem lies within the if block. Now, how to make everything work along with a file attach...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the 'add-attachment'-code in your loop is checking for empty filenames, it is safe to do this within the `$file_count` statement as well.

Change

```
$file_count = count($attachments['name']);
```

into

```
$file_count = count(array_filter($attachments['name']));
```

Thus counting only the non-empty filenames.

Comment: Awesome, this got the expected if/else logic to work. Thanks! Any ideas on where to stick the "email, comments, telephone, etc" concatenations to $body to get all that info to show up when an attachment is present? The body of a form submission email with an attachment only shows what was written in the comments box with the current code. Adding more info to the end of the code block that starts with `//message text` isn't working.

Comment: Store mail-text in a new variable (for example called `$mailText`), then replace the `$message` with `$mailText`. Extra hint (if you got that working): place all `$mailText = ...` just above the `if` so you could use the same variable in your else-part (`$body = $mailText;`)

Comment: This worked for holding all the user info and sending it when there is no attachment,  but form submissions with attachments still send with just the comment box text (+ the attachment). I tried `$body .= chunk_split(base64_encode($mailText));` (this sent just the comment box text) and simply resetting the variable to `$body = $mailText` right under that (this sent no text at all).

Comment: Did you replace the `$body .= chunk_split(base64_encode($message));` by `$body .= chunk_split(base64_encode($mailText));` or did you just add that line? The latter wont work indeed. And of course you should fill $mailText first with the correct text.

Comment: I tried the former and the latter separately. I actually just got it to work! I had to add the mailText variable in two places but it ended up working. Once here: http://imgur.com/iR1hGgk and once here: http://imgur.com/qWR4lQo . Thank you for all your help!

Comment: No you don't. You definetely should remove the last one (just after the `$encoded_content`) as it could mess up your attachment.

Comment: Hmmm good call. For some reason when I tested it, it didn't work until I added it in both sections. Must've been missing something. Removing the second instance of it works just fine. Thanks for the heads up.